# Bubble sort does not iterate?

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm creating a bubble sort function in Python for homework, but although I have checked my code, I can't figure out why the function does not iterate. For example, I have my code set so that it prints each step of the sorting, but when I call it with this list:

```
bubblesort([2,1,3,6,5,4])
```

it only sorts and outputs the first two mismatched numbers it encounters,

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
```

and does not check if there are any other mismatches.

This is my full code here:

```
def bubblesort(lis):
    sortedd = False
    while sortedd == False:
        sortedd = True
        for i in range(0, len(lis)):
            if lis[i] > lis[i+1]:
                sortedd = False
                lis[i],lis[i+1] = lis[i+1],lis[i]
                print(lis)
            return lis
```

I've checked other questions but I cannot find a solution; help please?

Comment: Check the indentation of `return lis`. You're breaking out of the function before you iterate through your full `for` loop.

Comment: When you do `return`, the whole function finishes, so your for loop only executes once. Move your  `return` outside the scope of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, when `i == len(lis)`, `lis[i+1]` will cause an index error.  Use `range(0, len(lis)-1)`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that 'return' ended the entire function, I thought it only broke out of the current loop.

Comment: @cqubit To break out of a loop use `break`.

Comment: @cqubit But breaking out of the loop would also be wrong, since it means you would only loop once.